# Mangos on flight from Palawan to Manila?

Tags: food-and-drink, philippines

I'm on a flight from Puerto Princesa to Manila this Saturday. Can I bring on board mangos? There were some restrictions earlier due to some weevil thing but I'm not sure if they've been lifted.

Comment: Are you asking if you can bring them on board, or whether you'll be permitted to bring them into Manila?

Comment: On board as carry on, then I transit a few hours later, in Manila airport taking a different airline to Singapore.

Comment: The best mangos in the world are available in Manila.  Why carry mangos to Manila?

Comment: Now that you have probably travelled, did you find out whether they were allowed?

Comment: There's an easy way to find out: Bring a mango and declare it on your landing card. Officials will then inform you if it is allowed or not, with no penalty if it's not allowed.

Comment: @KennyLJ Does my answer sufficiently answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

Flying from Palawan to Manilla is classed as a **domestic flight**, because you are not leaving the Philippines.

For this flight, you will need to go through customs at Manilla unlike other domestic flights due to the set-up of the airport. However, this will not be a problem as you are **not importing** mangoes into the country, just moving them across the country.

The place where the problem may have occurred is in Singapore, as there are tight regulations on the importation of food products. The rules for fruit and vegetables are as follows;

> Each person is allowed a small, reasonable quantity (i.e. hand-carried size) of fruit and vegetable products for personal consumption
>
> However, a phytosanitary certificate from the country's competent authority is required for fresh fruits and vegetables from the American Tropics, which includes:
> Barbados, Belize, Bolivia, Brazil, Colombia, Cuba, Costa Rica, Dominica, Dominican Rep, Ecuador, El Salvador, French Guyana, Grenada, Guadeloupe, Guatemala, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Jamaica, Martinique, Mexico, Nicaragua, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Puerto Rico, St Lucia, St Vincent and the Grenadines, Suriname, Trinidad and Tobago, Venezuela, Virgin Islands

[Source - Ava.og.sg](http://www.ava.gov.sg/explore-by-sections/food/bringing-food-into-singapore-and-exporting/bringing-food-for-personal-use)

**In short - it is okay to import mangoes into Singapore for personal use from Manilla, as this is not one of the countries stated above.** Only a reasonable quantity is allowed into the country - the question stated it would be a carry on item, so this is a suitable quantity.

There should potentially be no problem with mangoes going on board an aircraft as a carry on item, as long as it fits in with your airline's regulations. These can usually be found on their website.

If you are unsure of regulations, it is always best to contact your airline before departure, rather than get into a sticky situation aboard.

Comment: The OP was transferring to Singapore. Does that make a difference?

Comment: The OP is not importing anything since they're flying domestically within Philippines. Or are they?

Comment: If you have to go through customs in the Philippines, you cannot take mangoes. As I understand it, you need a licence to take such products into Singapore @Berwyn http://www.ava.gov.sg/docs/default-source/e-service/24web_cop_importandtranshipmentoffreshfruitsandveg.pdf?sfvrsn=2

Comment: Does this answer your question @KennyLJ ?

Comment: @NathanShoesmith that link seems to be for commercial importing. Fruit is allowed according to this link: http://www.ava.gov.sg/explore-by-sections/food/bringing-food-into-singapore-and-exporting/bringing-food-for-personal-use Some restictions there too. And not sure about transferring through Manila

Comment: @Berwyn It sounds like from the comments in the question that there is a wait in Manilla before transfer. If this is the case, mangoes would be seized at manilla before getting next flight to singapore

Comment: There is, but I think it's a domestic connection. Not sure what that's going to mean though.

Comment: Yes @Berwyn your link seems to say that mangoes are allowed in, just whether or not they were to stop off in Manilla

Comment: Reading up on other airports, a domestic connection would mean you not needing to go through passport control - therefore not customs. Not sure if this applies in Manilla @Berwyn

Comment: ok, I think you need to revise your answer a bit then

Comment: Revised answer, do you think that it is okay now @Berwyn ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40560/discussion-between-berwyn-and-nathan-shoesmith).

Answer (score 5):

There is a current infestation of mangoes in Palawan, so they are not allowed to be brought outside of Palawan to anywhere. I read that at the airport in El Nido Palawan just recently, July 2019.