# Bringing mangos from the UK to Russia as a gift

Tags: food-and-drink, russia, import-taxes

There is an existing question here [Mangos on flight from Palawan to Manila?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/mangos-on-flight-from-palawan-to-manila) that addresses a different case.

We are hopping over to Russia tomorrow, I will return the same day/next day but my family will stay on for several weeks.  Our family members there have asked us to bring some fresh mangos (we can get them at the Tesco here in Essex).  No clue as to whether or not the authorities will get upset about this. We are all Russian nationals so there's standard immigration formalities, but do mangos need to be declared or certified? Is it ok?

At request, we are also bringing two large jars of American peanut butter (one smooth, one crunchy). They are unopened and well within the 'use by' dates. Is it ok?

Comment: Always declare food, even if it's allowed into a country. It might take a few extra minutes to clear customs, but if you are caught bringing in undeclared food, most countries can issue hefty fines -- even if the food would be allowed!

Comment: I don't think there are mangos from the UK (unless from an overseas territory perhaps). They are most likely imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of anecdote, my relatives brought whole bags of fruit from e.g. Hong Kong. Don't think you need to declare it or anything.

It is *customary* to bring food from travels in Russia, even if there exist laws that de jure prohibit it.

Answer (score 4):

The food you're bringing should be ok.

There's no mention of fruit in the list of prohibited items on the Russian [customs](http://eng.customs.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1686&Itemid=1908) website, and since that's the ultimate authority (albeit with a strange English translation) my answer is, it's ok.

I found no mention of fruit or peanut butter anywhere else (though those were all traveller-type blogs) including [Frommers](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/russia/255718), however [IATA](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/RU-Russian-Federation-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) says you can't bring fruit into Russia.