# Can I bring Philippine mangoes into France via checked-in luggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, france, philippines

Can I bring Philippine mangoes to France without fuss (i.e. no need for some authority to inspect it) via checked-in luggage? If so, what is the maximum weight that I can bring?

I did my due diligence and used the search feature and found tangentially related questions (with answers) that DO NOT answer this question.

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149609/mangoes-and-bananas-from-manila-to-switzerland/149635#149635) talks about Swiss regulations but does not say anything about France. If I understand correctly, Philippine mangoes need a phytosanitary certificate to be brought into Switzerland. The accepted answer also talks that regulations may vary across other EU countries but does not talk about France. Therefore, my question is not a duplicate of this one.

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/mangos-on-flight-from-palawan-to-manila) talks about bringing mangoes via domestic flights and talks about a "current" infestation of mangoes. This is an answer back in 2019 and the infestation might be finished by now. This concerns domestic flights and one of the answers tangentially talk about Singapore. Therefore, my question is not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: A quick internet search threw up what appears to be an official guide https://www.douane.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/2021-03/10/travellers-what-kinds-of-food-and-plants-can-you-bring-with-you.pdf

Comment: Follow-up question: [What's a non-personal luggage in the eyes of the EU customs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/173721/1810)

Comment: Most countries will have some form of restrictions for any fruit/vegetables/plants that may contain bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer : No.

According to French Customs, you need a phytosanitary certificate to import any plant, fruit or vegetable into France starting from the very first item.

From [Vous rapportez des végétaux, fruits et légumes en provenance d'un pays non membre de l’Union européenne ou en provenance des DROM](https://www.douane.gouv.fr/demarche/vous-rapportez-des-vegetaux-fruits-et-legumes-en-provenance-dun-pays-non-membre-de-lunion):

> L'importation de végétaux et produits végétaux dans les bagages des voyageurs en Union Européenne depuis les pays tiers (sauf depuis Andorre, Monaco et la Suisse) est soumise à la présentation obligatoire d'un certificat phytosanitaire et ce, dès le premier spécimen de végétaux.
>
> Ce certificat phytosanitaire est à obtenir avant le départ depuis le pays tiers de départ, auprès de l'autorité en charge de la protection des végétaux. Il est à présenter en douane en cas de contrôle lors de votre arrivée.

Google Translate:

> The importation of plants and plant products in the luggage of travelers to the European Union from third countries (except from Andorra, Monaco and Switzerland) is subject to the mandatory presentation of a phytosanitary certificate, from the first specimen of plants. .
>
> This phytosanitary certificate must be obtained before departure from the third country of departure, from the authority in charge of plant protection. It must be presented to customs in case of control upon your arrival.

Comment: Suggestion: change 'into France' to 'into the European Union' since that is what the quoted text states.